# Wordpress translate content without changing the page url

Tags: wordpress, translate

I will create a french website. In my website I will have to do translate of a few word/link, depending on whether the user is un located in France (fr_FR) or Canada (fr_CA).
I tested polylang, but I believe it is too huge for me.
Do you know how I could do that easily?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WPML is what I use for multilanguage sites, it is not free, but works. The Multilingual CMS is more complete and expensive.